# Python script for writing an API key into excel

Tags: python, excel, api, command-prompt

I need to take the API key `u+QBLoEyLWGS…` (this is an arbitrary key) at the command prompt and insert it into a particular cell of an excel sheet. Any ideas regarding how to write a python script to achieve this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use existing libraries such as [Openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/), which supports all kinds of operations on Excel sheets. Install using

```
pip install openpyxl
```

If you want to take input from the command line, you can use the [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) keyword

```
API_key = input("What is the API key? \n")
```

Then use Openpyxl to add this into your cell on the excel sheet. Taken directly from the Openpyxl docs:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be assigned directly to cells
ws['A1'] = API_key

# Save the file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```